# SignalR for .NET Core 2.1 in docker not working after moving project to new PC

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, signalr

## UPDATE: SOLVED (read below)

I created this project on PC1. I've been working on it for a while when I found SignalR. After implementing, and making SignalR work, I had to move to a new PC, so I saved the project folder and moved it to the new PC. I installed Docker for Windows, the .NET Core 2.1 SDK and VS. I put the project in the same folder (C:\users\xxx\source\repos). Now when I run it it works as expected, but the client (browser) doesn't react on SignalR calls from the server. Because I don't have functions being called from the client I'm not using a custom Hub.

My issue is this: As soon as I try to set up the SignalR connection to the server from the JS, it tells me in the JS-Console it couldn't find a matching constructor. When looking at the hub object using a breakpoint in `AddMessage()`, it is not null, so some kind of constructer is working.

I have no idea what to do.

## Error message:

`Connection disconnected with error 'Error: Server returned an error on close: Connection closed with an error. InvalidOperationException: A suitable constructor for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Hub' could not be located. Ensure the type is concrete and services are registered for all parameters of a public constructor.'.`

## My Code:

### in Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    //...

    services.AddSignalR(o =>
    {
        o.EnableDetailedErrors = true;
    });
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    //...

    app.UseSignalR(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapHub<Hub>("/shoutboxHub");
    });

    //...
}
```

### in HomeController.cs

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly ShoutboxDbContext context;
    private readonly IHubContext<Hub> hub;

    public HomeController(ShoutboxDbContext context, IHubContext<Hub> hub)
    {
        this.hub = hub;
        this.context = context;
    }

    //...

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult AddMessage([FromBody]Message input)
    {
        //...

        hub.Clients.All.SendAsync("Refresh");

        return Json((Object)true);
    }
}
```

### in Index.js

```
var connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl("/shoutboxHub").build();

connection.on("Refresh", function () {
    updateMessageBox();
});

connection.start().catch(function (err) {
    return console.error(err.toString());
});
```

Comment: It looks like you've solved your problem, but not sure what you mean.

I always Assumed one would have to implement a Hub, ie derive from a Hub (creating your own) If you called your Hub (Hub) then maybe there was a scope/referencing issue that was not being your implementation?

Comment: @MarkRedman `Hub` is an `abstract` type, meaning it can't be instantiated and has to be inhereted to be used. I guess that makes it _not_ concrete. I just don't get why using `Hub` as my hub worked on the first PC... maybe in the meantime there was an update to the NuGet package making `Hub` `abstact`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## UPDATE:

Okay, I got it working again. The issue apparently was that `Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Hub` apparently isn't a concrete type. How exactly that is defined and in what sense `Hub` is not concrete, I don't know. I only know that this rediculous fix solved my problem:

I made my own Hub called `ShoutboxHub`:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;

namespace Shoutbox.Hubs
{
    public class ShoutboxHub : Hub
    {
    }
}
```

... and changed the three lines containing `Hub` to `ShoutboxHub` (and added `using Shoutbox.Hubs;`, but that goes without saying). That's it.